# Passing ArrayList in a bundle

Tags: android, arraylist, bundle

how can i put an arraylist in a bundle? I have used this, but it is wrong:

```
   Bundle bundTemasSel = new Bundle();
   ArrayList<TemaRescatado> arraydirGen = dataAdapter.temaGenList;
   bundTemasSel.putParcelableArray("arraySel", arraydirGen);
```

The object TemaRescatado has this code:

```
  public class TemaRescatado {

    protected String tema;
    protected long id;
    protected Boolean selected = false;

    ...


}
```

Comment: if I were in you, I would start making `TemaRescatado` implements `Parcelable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TemaRescatado` has to implement `Parcelable` in order to do `putParcelableArray` So you need:

```
public class TemaRescatado implements Parcelable {
    // variables
    // Parcelable methods
}
```